# Django ORM leaves idle connections on Postgres DB

Tags: django, postgresql, database-connection, django-orm

Recently, my Django app has been crashing frequently due to database connection errors:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

When I go into the app database, I see that indeed there are nearly 100 open connections, all with the same query (executed by the Django ORM) and all in the `idle` state.

I have been manually doing `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle';` but I am perplexed as to why this is happening. Can anyone shed any insight into what is happening here?

My Django database settings do not stray from the defaults (I have not defined `CONN_MAX_AGE` or anything of that nature).

What could cause this? I'm not doing any advanced Django queries. Is this something that can be solved with a Django setting or perhaps some PostgreSQL configuration? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: try dropping this in the django IRC channel

Comment: Which Django version are you on?

Comment: @raiderrobert on Django 1.10.5

Answer (score 4):

Best guess without more details, but if it's the same query, and they're all idle, it feels like you're doing some kind of async programming, and you've hit a deadlock, and specifically your deadlock is manifesting itself in db connections getting saturated.

Comment: I see, thanks for this tip. I'll look into how I can detect a deadlock and see if that's what's going on here.

Comment: I encountered the same issue in my application. I tried to change the multiple threading to non-multi-threading method, that solved the problem. So I am looking for the way to insert/update db records in async way (Postgresql DB). Did you have any findings or good solution, @glifchits?

Answer (score 4):

apparently you don't disconnect. Using `db.close_connection()` after query finishes would help. Also If I get it right `CONN_MAX_AGE` to some short value could help. And consider using some session pooler, eg pgbouncer for django connections. This way if you have too many connections it will wait (or reuse previous, depending on config) instead of aborting execution with error...

**update**: explanation why I propose it

[from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#persistent-connections)

> each thread maintains its own connection, your database must support
>   at least as many simultaneous connections as you have worker threads.

So if you have more threads then postgres `max_connections`, you get mentioned error. Each thread can reuse connection if CONN_MAX_AGE has not passed. Your setting is 0, so connection should be closed after query completion, but you see 100 idle connection. So they are not closing. The big number of connection means that they are not reused either (logic: if you would have 100 parallel queries they would not all be idle, and if you have so many, they are not reused - opening new). So I think django does not close them as prommised - so CONN_MAX_AGE set to 0 does not work in your code. So I propose using `db.close_connection()` to force the disconnect and setting CONN_MAX_AGE to some small value can change behaviour.

Comment: I understand the idea of connection pooling but this application is not yet at the scale where introducing a 3rd party library to optimize database use is necessary. I also don't like the idea of going beyond what Django does to manage queries (i.e. calling `db.close_connection()` manually).

Comment: Regarding `CONN_MAX_AGE`: do you know if there are specific reasons why setting that value to a non-default is necessary, and why it might be the solution in this case?

Comment: I edited with explanation why I suppose CONN_MAX_AGE to small value could help. BTW connection pooling works from 1.9 - you have higher version do you?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not defined `CONN_MAX_AGE` and you're not using any third party pooler - then this must be an issue somewhere in your code or in a library you're using. Django by default opens and closes db connection per request. And the fact that you see idle connections in `pg_stat_activity` doesn't mean there is a deadlock - instead it means that something has opened these connections and didn't close it.

I would first make sure if these connections are actually coming from Django by e.g. restarting the app and seeing how it affects `pg_stat_activity`. If you confirm it, then check if you're not mixing any async or multiprocessing code there that leaves dangling threads/processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Django PostgreSQL Solution using Threading and Middleware.

**Database View**
You will need to create a view in you DB
Format: app_viewname
I called mine "configuration_terminate_idle_connections"

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY true::boolean) AS id,
pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE 
datname = 'database_name'
    AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
    AND state = 'idle'
    AND extract(epoch from (current_timestamp - query_start)) > 15*60;
```

**Model**

```
class terminate_idle_connections(models.Model):
    pg_terminate_backend = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        managed = False
        db_table = 'appname_terminate_idle_connections'
        verbose_name_plural = "Database Terminate Idle Connections"
```

**Admin (Run it manually through /admin)**

```
class terminate_idle_connectionsView(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'pg_terminate_backend')             


admin.site.register(terminate_idle_connections,terminate_idle_connectionsView)
```

**settings.py**
Set to what you want

```
DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 700
DB_MAX_IDLE_CONNECTIONS = 150
```

**Middleware (Run it when a request is submitted)**
I called mine "DbConnections.py" within the my_project_folder/middleware, the same location as the settings.py file
Full file path: "my_project_folder/middleware/DbConnections.py"

```
from django.conf import settings
from appname.models import *

class DbConnections:
    
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
    # PROCESSED BEFORE THE REQUESTED VIEW FUNCTION OR CLASS
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if settings.DEBUG: print("\nRemove idle Connections")
        dbConection= database_activity.objects.all()
        dbConectionCountAll= dbConection.count()
        dbConectionCountIdle= dbConection.filter(state="idle").count()
        if settings.DEBUG: print("    - Allowed Connections:",settings.DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS, "Actual Connections:",dbConectionCountAll)
        if settings.DEBUG: print("    - Allowed Idle Connections:",settings.DB_MAX_IDLE_CONNECTIONS, "Actual Idle Connections:",dbConectionCountIdle)
        if dbConectionCountAll >= settings.DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS or dbConectionCountIdle >= settings.DB_MAX_IDLE_CONNECTIONS:
            terminateIdelConections = terminate_idle_connections.objects.all()
            if settings.DEBUG: print("\n    - Terminated Connections:", terminateIdelConections.count(),"\n")
```

**Settings Middleware**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'my_project_folder.Middleware.DbConnections.DbConnections',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

**View Threading (Run it on a timer)**
Within you app views.py file:

```
import threading
from django.conf import settings
from appname.models import *

def removeIdleDbConnections():
    threading.Timer(900, removeIdleDbConnections).start()


    # REMOVE IDLE CONNECTIONS
    try:
        dbConection= database_activity.objects.all()
        dbConectionCountAll= database_activity.objects.all().count()
        dbConectionCountIdle= database_activity.objects.filter(state="idle").count()
        if dbConectionCountAll >= settings.DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS or dbConectionCountIdle >= settings.DB_MAX_IDLE_CONNECTIONS:
            terminateIdelConections = terminate_idle_connections.objects.all()
            if settings.DEBUG: print("Terminated Connections:", terminateIdelConections.count())
    except:
        pass

removeIdleDbConnections()
```