# Django 1.7, postgresql, jquery datatables, and connections not being released

Tags: python, jquery, django, postgresql, datatables

I'm developing a page using jquery DataTables, django 1.7 and postgresql. I set up my DataTables to retrieve information from my django backend (set serverSide option to true). After some testing, I noticed that I kept getting this error from django

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

And upon checking pg_stat_activity, I've already reached the default 100 connections. I then checked the rows retrieved from pg_stat_activity and I noticed that there were a lot of "IDLE" connections. From what I read, the idle connections mean that the requests finished. These should have been released but for some reason, they are not being released causing the error

I've already checked CONN_MAX_AGE as suggested in this SO post
[Django ORM leaves idle connections on Postgres DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262566/django-orm-leaves-idle-connections-on-postgres-db)

but my CONN_MAX_AGE is zero. I've tried placing db.close_old_connections() in my fetch views which are referenced in the ajax of my DataTables but either I'm not using it properly or it's not working because the connections aren't closing

I am quite at my wit's end on how to fix this and I couldn't find any other similar situations compared to mine

Thanks

Comment: very strange. Are you sure that you are not opening connections manually (like `from django.db import connection` ... `cursor = connection.cursor()`) or something similar ?

Comment: @alfonso.kim Nope. The only django.db related things i've been using are Q objects and F objects.

Comment: You are not using the django development server in production by any chance are you?

Comment: @e4c5 nope. In production, we're using uwsgi and nginx. I noticed this during development i.e. running a development server in my local VM via runserver. I couldn't find the stack overflow post i found earlier but it says there that if the setup has a reverse proxy like nginx, nginx would manage the connections and would prevent this from happening. Also, every SO post or article I've read says that the connections are closed by django automatically so this error is very strange and quite frustrating.

Comment: Why don't you post the full stacktrace

Comment: also, check with `pg_stat_activity` if all connections come from django

Comment: @alfonso.kim totally forgot the stack trace. Here's the [paste bin for the stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/sHLiaTMj) and for the stat_activity, how do i check if the connections are from django? As far as i could tell, i think they are. Here is the output of [pg_stat_activity](http://www.filedropper.com/pgstatactivity). Thanks

Comment: @e4c5 totally forgot about the stack trace. I think there's a signal doing a save on a session (request.session.save()) but it's not commiting the save. I will investigate and see if this is the case. thanks again guys

Comment: Stacktrace should be part of the question. At first glance you have a loottt of pending transactions.

Comment: @ec45 i've narrowed it down to this signal which executes at the end of every request. I think there's a deadlock occurring in that signal which updates session variables. Since multiple ajax requests run at once, i think they're trying to update the same session at the same time. I'm taking a look at it now. Thanks for the assistance. It was very helpful at pinpointing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it's in a signal i made before which runs after every request. There's an update of session variables occurring in that signal. Since this signal runs after every request, including ajax requests, i think a deadlock occurred with the session variable save causing the error. I've changed the code to be more specific about when the effects of the signal will take effect and the error has been fixed. Thank you for the direction provided @ec45 and @alfonso.kim